# How Progressive Apps are different from fully responsive sites?

Tags: responsiveness

Could someone elaborate on how Progressive web Apps are different from fully responsive sites?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app - responsiveness is just one of the attributes of a progressive app.

Answer (score 1):

From **Google**:

- Reliable - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in
  uncertain network conditions.
- Fast - Respond quickly to user
  interactions with silky smooth animations and no janky scrolling
- Engaging - Feel like a natural app on the device, with an immersive
  user experience.
  When launched from the user’s home screen, service workers enable a Progressive Web App to load instantly, regardless of the network state.

A service worker, written in JavaScript, is like a client-side proxy and puts you in control of the cache and how to respond to resource requests. By pre-caching key resources you can eliminate the dependence on the network, ensuring an instant and reliable experience for your users.

More here: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/